# SQLAlchemy PostgreSQL UPSERT array of values raises UnsupportedCompilationError

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

Trying to perform an UPSERT on an array of values to a PostgreSQL > 9.5.

Trying to build the statement as in the [SQLALchemy](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/postgresql.html#insert-on-conflict-upsert) docs, but there is no explanation about how to do it for an array instead of a single row. The insert statement builds properly so I suppose it's possible to do so with the on_conflict_do_update function.

Having this code :

```
stock_table = Table("stock_history", metadata,
            Column('date', sqlalchemy.types.NVARCHAR(length=255), primary_key=True),
            Column('product_id', sqlalchemy.types.INTEGER(), primary_key=True),
            Column('product_sku', sqlalchemy.types.NVARCHAR(length=255)), 
            Column('on_hand_qty',  sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.DOUBLE_PRECISION()),
            Column('available_qty',  sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.DOUBLE_PRECISION()),
            Column('output_qty', sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.DOUBLE_PRECISION())
        )
stock_today = pandas.read_sql_query(queryStock, odoo_engine)
insert_stmt = sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.insert(stock_table).values(stock_today)
upser_stmt = insert_stmt.on_conflict_do_update(
            index_elements=['date', 'product_id'],
            set_=stock_today.to_dict(orient='dict')
        )
```

I'm getting the following error:

AttributeError: 'StrSQLCompiler' object has no attribute 'visit_on_conflict_do_update'

```
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "pompeiiETL.py", line 15, in <module>
        pompeiiJobs.runStockJob(dwh_engine, odoo_prod_engine)
      File "/Users/alex/Development/DataLab/pompeii-datalab/pompeiiETL/jobs.py", line 54, in runStockJob
        print(upser_stmt)
      File "/Users/alex/Development/DataLab/ETLenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 446, in __str__
        return str(self.compile())
      File "<string>", line 1, in <lambda>
      File "/Users/alex/Development/DataLab/ETLenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 436, in compile
        return self._compiler(dialect, bind=bind, **kw)
      File "/Users/alex/Development/DataLab/ETLenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 442, in _compiler
        return dialect.statement_compiler(dialect, self, **kw)
      File "/Users/alex/Development/DataLab/ETLenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/compiler.py", line 435, in __init__
        Compiled.__init__(self, dialect, statement, **kwargs)
      File "/Users/alex/Development/DataLab/ETLenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/compiler.py", line 216, in __init__
        self.string = self.process(self.statement, **compile_kwargs)
      File "/Users/alex/Development/DataLab/ETLenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/compiler.py", line 242, in process
        return obj._compiler_dispatch(self, **kwargs)
      File "/Users/alex/Development/DataLab/ETLenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/visitors.py", line 81, in _compiler_dispatch
        return meth(self, **kw)
      File "/Users/alex/Development/DataLab/ETLenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/compiler.py", line 2041, in visit_insert
        insert_stmt._post_values_clause, **kw)
      File "/Users/alex/Development/DataLab/ETLenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/compiler.py", line 242, in process
        return obj._compiler_dispatch(self, **kwargs)
      File "/Users/alex/Development/DataLab/ETLenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/visitors.py", line 79, in _compiler_dispatch
        raise exc.UnsupportedCompilationError(visitor, cls)
    sqlalchemy.exc.UnsupportedCompilationError: Compiler <sqlalchemy.sql.compiler.StrSQLCompiler object at 0x105b55be0> can't render element of type <class 'sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.dml.OnConflictDoUpdate'>
```

What I'm ding wrong? Is there a better way to do an upsert?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are trying to get string representation of `Insert`-object that has no proper bind, if we write

```
db_uri = make_url('your-postgres-db-uri-here')
engine = create_engine(db_uri)
upser_stmt.bind = engine
print(upser_stmt)
```

it works

We can also create insert statement with bind specified

```
insert_stmt = sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.insert(stock_table,
                                                    bind=engine).values(stock_today)
upser_stmt = insert_stmt.on_conflict_do_update(
    index_elements=['date', 'product_id'],
    set_=stock_today.to_dict(orient='dict')
)
```

Comment: Hey there! Thanks! With your help I managed to perform the Insert statment as follows:
`insert_stmt=sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.insert(stock_table, bind=dwh_engine).values(stock_today.to_dict(orient='records'))`

But if I try to add the on_conflict_do_update, adding the same data I get an error:
`raise ValueError("set parameter must be a non-empty dictionary")
ValueError: set parameter must be a non-empty dictionary`

how it's working for the insert and saying it's empty for the upsert? :S

Comment: feel free to ask another question, but not in comments: more users can help you

Comment: for me error message is clear: you need to check if your `set_` argument is a non-empty dictionary

Comment: Hi! What if I want to use this using Sessions?

Comment: @Tata: try to use `Session.execute` method and pass built statement to it

Comment: @AzatIbrakov: I did try using `Session.execute` but somehow I always get `sqlalchemy.exc.CompileError: Unconsumed column names:`

Comment: @Tata: you should ask a separate question then since this is not related to OP